# Why does Kaede hold her chopsticks up while talking?

Tags: shuffle

In *Shuffle!*, Kaede seems to always hold her chopsticks up while talking at table. According to [a blog](https://www.umami-insider.com/chopstick-etiquette/#:%7E:text=talking%20while%20holding%20your%20chopsticks%20is%20deemed%20to%20be%20terrible%20manners.) on chopstick etiquette, it's rude to do that.

> You may be used to talking while holding your fork and knife. However, **talking while holding your chopsticks is deemed to be terrible manners.**

[image]

[image]

Is this a sign that Kaede does not care much about others, which is verified later in the anime by her being yandere?

Comment: "which is verified later in the anime by her being yandere" - Doesn't this statement answer your own question?

Comment: @Wondercricket I meant her not caring about others is verified, not the purpose of the design that she holds up chopsticks is verified.